# Why this PHP foreach wont loop through every item in an array that got the information from a json string?

Tags: php, json, foreach

I have this json string that it's stored as text in a mysql database (I have that in a "cronograma" field).

This is what `$row['cronograma']` outputs:

> {"fecha":["02 enero","05 enero","20 enero","22 enero","25
>   enero"],"bolilla":["22","26","15","28","33"],"docente":["Juan","Pedro","Lidia","Maxima","Luis"]}

And I want to extract the information from it, and presented it in screen.

This is how I extract the information with `json_decode()` and loop through it with a foreach:

```
    $cronograma = json_decode($row['cronograma'], true);
    $cant = count($cronograma['fecha']);
    echo $cant.'<br>'; //this outputs 5
    $i = 0;
      foreach ($cronograma as $key => $value) {
          echo $i;
          $fecha = $cronograma['fecha'][$i];
          $bolilla = $cronograma['bolilla'][$i];
          $docente = $cronograma['docente'][$i];

          echo "<b>Fecha:</b> $fecha <b>Bolilla:</b> $bolilla <b>Docente:</b> $docente<br>";

          if ($i < $cant) $i++;
      }
```

Now, my problem is that it won't output the five items in the array, but just three, and I don't understand why. Even if I change `($i < $cant)` to `($i < 5)`, it still outputs only 3.

This is the output:

```
0Fecha: 02 enero Bolilla: 22 Docente: Juan

1Fecha: 05 enero Bolilla: 26 Docente: Pedro

2Fecha: 20 enero Bolilla: 15 Docente: Lidia
```

And this is what it should be:

```
0Fecha: 02 enero Bolilla: 22 Docente: Juan

1Fecha: 05 enero Bolilla: 26 Docente: Pedro

2Fecha: 20 enero Bolilla: 15 Docente: Lidia

3Fecha: 22 enero Bolilla: 28 Docente: Maxima

4Fecha: 25 enero Bolilla: 33 Docente: Luis
```

What am I missing?

Comment: what you get is what you have. You are mis-interpreting the underlying data structure.

Comment: I know that, but in what way?

Comment: any answer is probably a wild guess, but i suspect you have either a broken data model (server side) ... or a broken query servicing a well thought out data model. You are receiving 3 properties of a more cogent 'Fully Qualified Course' object, each as an array. You should be receiving an array of the said object. The real issue is probably how you get 'cronograma' ...

Comment: It's not an issue with your json. It's looping the exact amount as stored. You should check your SQL query, it probably has a LIMIT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `$cronograma` contains 3 items; `fecha`, `bolilla` & `docente`, so I recommend changing your loop like:

```
    $cronograma = json_decode($row['cronograma'], true);
    $cant = count($cronograma['fecha']);
    echo $cant.'<br>'; //this outputs 5

      for ($i = 0; $i < $cant; $i++) {
          echo $i;
          $fecha = $cronograma['fecha'][$i];
          $bolilla = $cronograma['bolilla'][$i];
          $docente = $cronograma['docente'][$i];

          echo "<b>Fecha:</b> $fecha <b>Bolilla:</b> $bolilla <b>Docente:</b> $docente<br>";
      }
```

Comment: An example of where to use that would have made this from a  comment into an answer

Comment: sure, edited, thought the explanation might be clear enough

Comment: yet the accepted answer is obviously incorrect, the foreach loop and its values aren't used

Comment: I've accepted the reply before seeing yours.
Yours is more clean, but both works.

Comment: @Rosamunda you can always change your accepted answer, and my feelings won't be hurt ;)

Comment: @JeffPuckettII Better to fix your answer regardless of it being accepted or not

Comment: @Riggs I did following the suggestion of user114

Comment: Well, I changed the accepted answer as I ended up using user114's answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

You just need a while loop to go through `$cant`

```
<?php

$cronograma = '{"fecha":["02 enero","05 enero","20 enero","22 enero","25 enero"],"bolilla":["22","26","15","28","33"],"docente":["Juan","Pedro","Lidia","Maxima","Luis"]}';

$cronograma = json_decode($cronograma, true);
$cant = count($cronograma['fecha']);
echo $cant.'<br>'; //this outputs 5
$i = 0;

while ($i < $cant){
    $fecha = $cronograma['fecha'][$i];
    $bolilla = $cronograma['bolilla'][$i];
    $docente = $cronograma['docente'][$i];

    echo "<b>Fecha:</b> $fecha <b>Bolilla:</b> $bolilla <b>Docente:</b> $docente<br>";

    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Why bother using a foreach loop?

Comment: @user114111121 hey you're right, thanks, I've updated my answer! I had to google translate because I didn't understand the data context - I was just trying to match the OP's desired output with the least amount of changes I could think of.

Answer (score 2):

i think your foreach loop causing the problem...you are using 'cronograma' as your foreach loop array which has only three elements 'fecha' ,'bolilla' & 'docente' so the loop runs only thrice no matter what value you set for variable i against  'cant'

```
$x='{"fecha":["02 enero","05 enero","20 enero","22 enero","25 enero"],"bolilla":["22","26","15","28","33"],"docente":["Juan","Pedro","Lidia","Maxima","Luis"]}';
$cronograma = json_decode($x, true);
    $cant = count($cronograma['fecha']);
    echo $cant.'<br>'; //this outputs 5
    $i = 0;
      for($i=0;$i<$cant;$i++) {
          echo $i;
          $fecha = $cronograma['fecha'][$i];
          $bolilla = $cronograma['bolilla'][$i];
          $docente = $cronograma['docente'][$i];

          echo "<b>Fecha:</b> $fecha <b>Bolilla:</b> $bolilla <b>Docente:</b> $docente<br>";

      }
```